# Convert a integer column to string IP in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with IPv4 values as integers, and I want to convert them into their string form. Preferably without a UDF that might have a large performance impact.

Example input:

```
+---------------+
|         IP_int|
+---------------+
|       67633643|
|      839977746|
|      812147536|
+---------------+
```

Example output:

```
+---------------+
|         IP_str|
+---------------+
|      4.8.1.235|
|    50.17.11.18|
|   48.104.99.80|
+---------------+
```

Comment: can you please show your code or tell us where is the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You convert to HEX with `conv`, split into 4 pieces with `substring`, convert it back to decimal with `conv`, and join it with `concat_ws`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("hex", F.lpad(F.conv("IP_int", 10, 16), 8, "0"))

df.select(
    "IP_int",
    F.concat_ws(
        ".",
        F.conv(F.substring("hex", 1, 2), 16, 10),
        F.conv(F.substring("hex", 3, 2), 16, 10),
        F.conv(F.substring("hex", 5, 2), 16, 10),
        F.conv(F.substring("hex", 7, 2), 16, 10),
    ).alias("IP_str"),
).show()

+---------+------------+
|   IP_int|      IP_str|
+---------+------------+
| 67633643|   4.8.1.235|
|839977746| 50.17.11.18|
|812147536|48.104.99.80|
+---------+------------+
```

---

**EDIT**: Using bit shift operator

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "IP_str",
    F.concat_ws(
        ".",
        (F.shiftRight("IP_int", 8*3) % 256).cast("string"),
        (F.shiftRight("IP_int", 8*2) % 256).cast("string"),
        (F.shiftRight("IP_int", 8) % 256).cast("string"),
        (F.col("IP_int") % 256).cast("string"),
    ),
)
```

Comment: much more elegant than my solution. This is the correct answer.

Comment: @DavidTaub Yours is pretty elegant too. And probably faster. Just replace you `concat` with `concat_ws`

Comment: @DavidTaub Added new version using Bitwise shift. Probably the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

This code will convert ip from integer to string:

```py
ip_str_col = f.concat_ws(
    ".",
    ((f.col("IP_int") / 16777216).cast("int") % 256).cast("string"),
    ((f.col("IP_int") / 65536).cast("int") % 256).cast("string"),
    ((f.col("IP_int") / 256).cast("int") % 256).cast("string"),
    (f.col("IP_int").cast("int") % 256).cast("string"),
)
df = df.withColumn("IP_str", ip_str_col)
df.show()
```

Outputs:

```
+---------+------------+
|   IP_int|      IP_str|
+---------+------------+
| 67633643|   4.8.1.235|
|839977746| 50.17.11.18|
|812147536|48.104.99.80|
+---------+------------+
```